# Non Sorted listview(Display as it is inserted)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Here my `adminModel.fields.distinctBodyParts = ['d','a','c','b']`

```
 <div style="float:left;width:100%;margin-top:2px">
                <h3 id="routineNameId"></h3>
                <ul id="routineTemplateHeader" data-role="listview" data-bind="source: adminModel.fields.distinctBodyParts" 
                    data-template="item-template" data-header-template="header-template" ></ul>
                <script id="header-template" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl"> #: value # </script>
                <script id="item-template" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl"> #: bodyPart # </script>
            </div>
```

But i am getting `['a','b','c','d']` always the list is sorted alphabetically how to display the list in original insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

I would create another table let's say 'ItemNo' Field. Then I will get the data based on the selection from 'ItemNo' Field during inserting. Maybe hide the 'ItemNo' elsewhere

Comment: use another field on sorting your desired value. If a user enters a data one by one, maybe you could do someting like 'ITEM NO' Textbox hide it and make it an automatic numbering based on the user entry ordering.